# Ionic Rest API call not working from device

Tags: node.js, rest, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building my first app using ionic framework. I run into the following issue. I have a nodejs rest api hosted in the cloud. When I run my app using **ionic serve** and I fetch some data it does work. But when I do it from my device (using **ionic run android**) it doesnt work.
I've read something about cordova-plugin-whitelist, but I have it and still doesnt work.

```
ionic.project
{
"name": "myApp",
"app_id": "",
"proxies": [
  {
    "path": "/contacts",
    "proxyUrl": "https://myapp.herokuapp.com/contacts"
  }
]
}
```

In config.xml I have both of this tags:

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

I forgot to mention that I tried accessing to this other api https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random and it has no problems with it. Maybe somethings wrong with my nodejs REST service?

Comment: remove platform and add it again..!then run `ionic run android`

Comment: Didnt work. I think it migth have something to do with my service and not with ionic.

Comment: This plugin will resolve this issue when testing your applicationn within a Chrome Borwser: Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through this same problem, I tried all possibilities. I installed the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` plugin. It includes the settings in `config.xml`, the `<meta>` with CSP (Content-Security-Policy) and even then I couldn't solve the problem. I did all possible procedures and it still doesn't work.

It worked on the `ionic serve` and `ionic run -l` but it did not work on the device. When I was giving up, I realized that when I included the URLs of other servers it worked, and not worked for my URL. I thought it was a problem in my server or in my API.

Until I saw that my constant referring to URL was without `http`, because as it did in normal programming in AngularJS, put the constant `//api.example.com/`, and leaves the browser responsible for including it. But it does not happen on the device, so I did not access my API.

I do not know if that was your case, but it took me a long time to find out and I'd like to share it with you.

Comment: "Until I saw that my constant referring to URL"
how did you check that on device

Comment: @manishkumar You can see using the AVD via command line, see it: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html

Comment: how in the world its work for you, application cant detect the URL // without HTTP://

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tag in your index.html

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src   'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case ,I just installed **cordova-plugin-whitelist** plugin .And the issue was resolved.Hope it helps someone.

Happy coding :)